# Make List of several "GM_listValues", calling a function to remove themselves

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm currently working on a Greasemonkey script, that allows to add users to an ignore list which will block their comments from being rendered.

I store their userID via "GM_setValue". Everything is working just fine but I have problems to render the "Manage your ban-list" part of my script to pardon a user.

**The codeblock I have troubles with:**

```
var banList = GM_listValues(); // Array of Usernames
var manageBans = $("#content_content"); //The <div> I want to render the Banlist in.
manageBans.append("<h4>Manage ignorelist</h4>");


for (var i=0; i < banList.length; i++) {
    var currentUser = banList[i];   

    manageBans.append($('<b>'+currentUser+'</b><a href ="javascript:void(null)"><img src="/redaktion/style/delete.png" width="16" height="16" alt="unblock_user"></a></br>').click(function(){ unbanUser(currentUser)}));
}


var unbanUser = function(name) {                    
        GM_deleteValue(name);
};
```

So basically this is working fine, all banned users are rendered in a list and I can click to unban. But once I click at any user to call "unbanUser", the last user in the list gets unbanned and not the one I clicked at.

I guess the variable "currentUser" is always the last name on the list, I kinda wanted it to be a fix link for each user after the for-loop is finished.
It's quite a trivial task but I don't find a proper solution.

Do you have a hint for me?
Greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the loop, `currentUser` keeps getting overwritten on each iteration. Inside the `click` function, you're referring to `currentUser`, which equals the last definition of `currentUser`.

To fix it, make use of closures:

```
function doSomething(currentUser) {
    manageBans.append($('<b>'+currentUser+'</b><a href="javascript:void(null)"><img src="/redaktion/style/delete.png" width="16" height="16" alt="unblock_user"></a></br>').click(function(){
        unbanUser(currentUser)
    }));
}

for (var i=0; i < banList.length; i++) {
    doSomething(banList[i]);
}
```