# How do I pass a variable inside of an ajax call which is inside of a for loop (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, scope

Working with an api and I need to one of the first responses alongside with the second response in order to serve up a new page. The problem I'm facing is that my variable $x is always set to whatever the last # is in the loop, ie 103 in this specific case. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
dataType: 'text',
type: 'post',
url: 'getAllMessages.php',
success: function(responseData) {
    var newString = responseData;
    var newerString = newString.substring(0, newString.length - 1);
    $newObject = jQuery.parseJSON(newerString);
    //console.log($newObject);
    for($x = 0; $x < $newObject.messages.length; $x++){
        $.ajax({
            data: {clientFolderId: $newObject.messages[$x].clientFolderId, messageId: $newObject.messages[$x].messageId},
            dataType: 'text',
            type: 'post',
            url: 'testapi.php',
            success: function(responseData2){
                //alert($x);
                var newString2 = responseData2;
                var newerString2 = newString2.substring(0, newString2.length - 1);
                $newObject2 = jQuery.parseJSON(newerString2);
                if($newObject2.statistics.delivered > 1000){
                    console.log($newObject.messages[$x]);
                    console.log($newObject2);
                }
            },
            error: function(responseData2){
                alert('failure in testapi.php');
            }
        });
    }
},
error: function(responseData) {
    alert('failure in getAllMessages.php');
}
```

});

Comment: I hope $newObject.messages.length is short! Running ajax calls in a loop like this could completely kill your users browser.. Not to mention you have a limit in most browsers as to how many http requests you can make, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My intuition says nesting the Ajax call inside another functional scope (correction thanks to Matt) will resolve the unexpected behavior. I got burned by this already [Object creation in loop broken; unrolled works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095371/object-creation-in-loop-broken-unrolled-works)

Also here, example #5: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures2.shtml

Following the pattern given by Engineer,

```
for($x = 0; $x < $newObject.messages.length; $x++){

   (function($x) {

    $.ajax({
        data: {clientFolderId: $newObject.messages[$x].clientFolderId, messageId: $newObject.messages[$x].messageId},
        dataType: 'text',
        type: 'post',
        url: 'testapi.php',
        success: function(responseData2){
            alert($x);
            var newString2 = responseData2;
            var newerString2 = newString2.substring(0, newString2.length - 1);
            $newObject2 = jQuery.parseJSON(newerString2);
            if($newObject2.statistics.delivered > 1000){
                console.log($newObject.messages[1]);
                console.log($newObject2);
            }
        },
        error: function(responseData2){
            alert('failure in testapi.php');
        }
    });

   })($x);
}
```

Comment: the closure isn't what is fixing it, what is fixing it is nesting it inside another functional scope, and passing the desired value in as a parameter to said function. Closures have nothing to do with it.

Comment: To clarify, nesting functions like that will let you do/use closures, but in this particular case it works because it gives the variable a new scope, which doesn't get updated on the next iteration of the loop

Comment: @Matt Time for me to read more about the definition of closure. It seems it gets thrown around indiscriminately. You're right about a function giving a new scope; I believe from experience that defining a function elsewhere that performs the inner Ajax call should also give the expected result.

Comment: To sum up a closure, if you are using an inner/nested function that references a variable in the outer scope, that is a closure.  If you are only using variables that are passed to the function, you are not using any closures.  In the example above, if $newObject is *not* a global object, then it is being "closured" by your inner function, which is why you can use it inside the inner function, even though originally it was in the scope of the outer/wrapping function.

Comment: also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the additional info and links

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing is closure. When the loop spins round, the value for `$x` is updated. However, when the ajax function comes to grab it - it's using a reference. So as you find, you end up with the last value.

Try and think more functional? What are you trying to do? Let's say you're trying to `postMessage` - wrap that in a function and pass in the message.

Your code will become easier to read, and you won't get your variables mangled.

I was about to throw out some code, but noticed something I wanted to clarify - you're using the index in both loops to get a single message from a messages array, yet the POST to `testapi.php` seems to be working on a single message? What kind of response is expected from that?

### Update: Created jsFiddle to Demo Problem

Here you go here's [some code](http://jsfiddle.net/robcthegeek/cjpF7/) to help you out.

```
    function correctOutputPlox(id) {
     setTimeout(function() {
       $("#output").append("<li>" + id + "</li>");
     }, 500);   
    }

    function runNicely() {
        // same loop...
        for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            // but rather than use 'x' (which is going to change, we pass it's value into a function which doesn't have access to the original 'x' since it's in a different lexical scope.
            correctOutputPlox(x);
        }
    }

    function showProblem() {
        for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#output").append("<li>" + x + "</li>");
            }, 500);
        }
    }

    showProblem();
    runNicely();
```